# Why do partials in Rails start with an underscore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure if this is convention or not, but I have been working through Hartl's Rails tutorial and I noticed that he creates all his partial files with a leading underscore.  For example _user.html.erb.  Is this something that is necessary for the partial to work, or is this a stylistic choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's necessary for partials to work. From the [official Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

> 3.4.1 Naming Partials
>
> To render a partial as part of a view, you use the render method within the view:
>
> `<%= render "menu" %>`
>
> This will render a file named _menu.html.erb at that point within the view being rendered. Note the leading underscore character: partials are named with a leading underscore to distinguish them from regular views, even though they are referred to without the underscore. This holds true even when you're pulling in a partial from another folder:

Comment: Will it still render if you leave out the underscore?

Comment: No. It'll probably throw an error saying that the partial was not found.